# list available spaCy language objects

Tags: spacy

I need to list the currently available spaCy language objects in `spacy.lang`[1](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/spacy/lang).  I have tried dir(spacy.lang) and searching the various options with no luck. How can I list the available language objects in the module?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found if it helps anyone else.  Use `spacy.__file__` to get the path for spaCy and then create a list of the directories in spacy/lang.

```py
import spacy
from pathlib import Path
spacy_path = Path(spacy.__file__.replace('__init__.py',''))
spacy_langs = spacy_path / 'lang'
SPACY_LANGS = [str(x).split('/')[-1] for x in spacy_langs.iterdir() if x.is_dir() and str(x).split('/')[-1] != '__pycache__']
```